# Redeclaring two Medium packages in One system component

Tags: fluid, modelica, openmodelica

I am new to modelica, and i don't have this much experience in it, but i got the basics of course. I am trying to model a micrfluidic network. The network consists of two sources of water and oil, controlled by two valves. The flow of the two mediums interact at a Tjunction and then into a tank or chamber. I don't care about the fluid properties of the mixture because its not my purpose. My question is how do redeclare two medium packages (water and oil) in one system component such as the Tjunction or a tank in order to simulate the system. In my real model, the two mediums doesn't meet, becuase every medium passes through the channels at a different time.

I attached the model with this message. Here's the link.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/yq6lg9la8z211uc/twomediumsv2.zip?dl=0

Thanks for the help .

Comment: No attachment is included in the question

Comment: @jrhodin I edited the question, and the attachment is there.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can redeclare a medium during simulation. In your case (where you don't need the mixing of the two fluids) you could create a new medium, for instance called `OilWaterMixture`, extending from `Modelica.Media.Interfaces.PartialMedium`.

If you look into the code of `PartialMedium` you'll see that it contains a lot of `partial` ("empty") functions that you should fill in in your new medium model. For example, in `OilWaterMixture` you should extend the function `specificEnthalpy_pTX` to return the specific enthalpy of your water/oil mixture, for a certain water/oil mixture (given by the mass fraction vector `X`). This could be done by adding the following model to the `OilWaterMixture` package:

```
redeclare function extends specificEnthalpy_pTX "Return specific enthalpy"
  Oil = Modelica.Media.Incompressible.Examples.Essotherm650;
  Water = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater;
algorithm 
  h_oil := Oil.h_pT(p,T);
  h_water := Water.specificEnthalpy_pT(p,T);
  h := X[0]*h_oil + X[1]*h_water;
end specificEnthalpy_pTX;
```

The mass fraction vector `X` is defined in `PartialMedium` and in `OilWaterMixture` you must define that it has two elements.

Again, since you are not going to actually use the mixing properties but only mass fraction vectors `{0,1}` or `{1,0}` the simple linear mixing equation should be adequate.

When you use `OilWaterMixture` in the various components, the error log will tell you which medium functions they need. So you probably don't need to extend all the partial functions in `PartialMedium`.